# what is difference between d[n:m][n:m] and df[n:m][m]?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying print values by using the following code I'm getting the output

```
print(df[2:5][1:3])
    0
46  4
45  5
```

But for the following code I'm getting error

```
print(df[2:5][2])
KeyError: 2
```

I'm using following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,19], index=[49,48,47,46,45, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

df[n:m][m] - [m] will be just a line.

Answer (score 0):

In short, `df[a:b]` slices your data frame by row number, equivalent to `df.iloc[a:b]` and `df[a]` slices your dataframe by **column name**. In this case, you dataframe does not have a column named `2`, so it gives you a `KeyError`.